# Is there a specific type of motion detector for use in long hallways?

Tags: lighting, motion-sensor

I would like to select a single [motion detector](https://www.grainger.com/search?searchBar=true&searchQuery=Wall%20switch%20motion) to drive lighting in a 70 foot hallway (straight corridor approximately 6 ft wide).  A 70 by 6 foot rectangle is to be covered. If it is necessary to use more than one detector then so be it, however less is more.

What are the specifications of a motion detector that describes it range in the  above context?

The current switch is a mechanical timer with maximum of 20 minutes.  A traditional switch, which can be left on indefinitely is not acceptable in this particular scenario. The switch should stay engage lighting for 10-20 minutes.

Comment: Er, doesn't range cover it? It's not clear to me what you're asking. The question seems circular.

Comment: It literally depends on which detector is selected and how perfectly it’s mounted for the application.  Visonic used to have a detector with a swappable lens where you could get alleged 10x70 hallway coverage.  They no longer offer that because most couldn’t figure out that to get that coverage it had to be mounted in the center of an end and exactly 8’ from the floor.  In general you’ll be better off with 2 detectors for that area, but other factors include where are entry and exits to the hall, how quickly must motion be detected, and how lenient can be be for false trips?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show a product I have located that is specially designed for hallways.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to wire in a device at a height of 7' on one end of the hallway, you can use this [Lithonia Acuity HW13 Hallway Sensor](https://www.cesco.com/Lithonia-Lighting-Acuity-HW13-Lithonia-Lighting-Acuity-HW13-Passive-Infrared-Low-Voltage-Hallway-Sensor-12-24-Volt-AC-DC-130-ft-White-Wall-Mount/p1925076) that will give you a straight line range of up to 130 feet.

[image]

When choosing a motion sensor, I usually take into consideration the motion angle and the square footage of the detector. We use 180 degree detectors in our hallways.

Here is a diagram of motion light switch that covers 180 degrees at up to 900 sq. feet. It would cover appx. 16.9 feet in either direction and up to 16.9 feet in front of it with an overall square footage of 900 square feet.

[image]

Comment: Square footage is kind of a silly specification to offer. It strikes me as a marketing tactic. Effective range is what matters.

Comment: It would seem that pdf spec sheet indicates a maximum of 30 feet.  If it it could span the length, then I would not need to run 140+ feet of wiring for this switch at the far end of the hall

Comment: Anecdotal : My 20 year old detectors on the garage trigger occasionally when a vehicle passes on the street 50 feet away.